# Преобразования JSON в ndarray

Tags: python, tensorflow

У меня программа выполняет код и выводит ndarray. Его ,в свою очередь, я преобразовываю в JSON и сохраняю в файл.

```
with open('encoding.txt', 'w') as fw:
# записываем
json.dump(pd.Series(unknown_face_encoding ).to_json(orient='values'), fw)
```

Затем, мне необходимо прочитать с этого файла данные. Я делаю это так:

```
 with open('encoding.txt', 'r') as fr:
    # читаем из файла
    lst1 = json.load(fr)
```

Но мне необходимо эти данные преобразовать обратно в ndarray. Какие способы есть?

Comment: а что мешает вам воспользоваться `numpy.save` сразу, минуя json вообще?

Comment: strawdog, благодарю за ответ, я к сожалению использую Python не для основной цели, а поддержку, и не совсем разбираюсь в данных случаях. За наводку спасибо

Comment: Cпасибо,друг. Работает все отлично.
Оформи в виде ответа